# ArgumentException: The prefab you want to instantiate is null

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, unityscript

I'm getting an error and I don't know why. From the error I can see that there is something wrong with line 12, I think.

The script is larger but is not needed to solve the problem.
But if you really need it, you can ask for it.

Here is the code:

```
if(RandomInt==2) {
    var randomNumberB = Random.Range(3,5);
    for(var b = 0; b < randomNumberB; b++) {
        var xCoB = childVector3.x + Random.Range(0,10);
        var zCoB = childVector3.z + Random.Range(0,10);
        var randomRotationB = Quaternion.Euler(0,Random.Range(0,360),0);
        var chancheB = Random.Range(0,2);
        if(chancheB == 0) {
            var bushC = Instantiate(bushes[Random.Range(0,bushes.length)], Vector3(xCoB, childVector3.y, zCoB), randomRotationB);
            bushC.transform.name = "bush";
        } else {
            Instantiate(cactus, Vector3(xCoB, childVector3.y, zCoB), randomRotationB).transform.name = "cactus";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Found this by googling:Take the prefab that you want to Instantiate and put it in a folder (you will have to create it in the project folder) called "Resources". Place the prefabs that you wish to Instantiate in there. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/416119/argumentexception-the-prefab-you-want-to-instantia-3.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `cactus` a prefab.

Then make a public variable:

```
 public GameObject cactus;
```

Then drag and drop the prefab into the script variable via de Editor. Then you can instantiate.

```
 if(cactus != null)
 {
    GameObject g = Instantiate(cactus, new Vector3(xCoB, childVector3.y, zCoB), randomRotation) as GameObject;

    g.name = "cactus";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

it is easy if you have prefabs sitting in the root Resources folder. It is different if you want them to be in a subfolder of Resources. You will need to create a "Prefabs" folder within.

Since you are using Javascript

1. Given a prefab named "Your Prefab.prefab" within Assets/Resources:

   ```
   var NewGameObject : GameObject = Resources.Load("Your Prefab"),Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity);
   ```

   This will allow you to have a reference to that prefab, loaded into memory.
2. If you wish to contain a prefab or more within a folder in Assets/Resources you must do the following:

   2a. Create a folder named "Prefabs" within Assets/Resources.

   2b. Create your folder there (e.g. "Resources/Prefabs/Your Prefab Folder");

   2c. Given a prefab named "Your Prefab.prefab":

   ```
   var NewGameObject : GameObject = Resources.Load("Prefabs/Your SubFolder/Your Prefab"),Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity);
   ```

Notes:

Don't forget to remove the ".prefab" extension.

The Unity manual states that you can load assets from Resources without supplying a path with folder names. Certainly in regards to prefabs (and javascript?) that does not seem to be true (Unity 4.6).